# Prove there are 3 real roots to this equation using Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I need to prove there are $3$ real solutions to $x^5 - 4x + 2 = 0$.

I know $f(-2)$ is negative, $f(0)$ is positive, $f(1)$ is negative, $f(2)$ is positive so that by IVT there are at least $3$ roots. Where I get confused is how to apply Rolle's theorem to show the uniqueness of these roots. I know that there must be a number $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$, but what step do I take after that?

Thanks

Comment: In such a case, one usually applies Rolle in an argument by contradiction. Assume there are at least $4$ zeros, then...

Answer (score 2):

The function is continuous, so

$f(-2)<0$ and $f(0)>0$ so there is $-2<x_1<0$ that $f(x_1)=0$.

$f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<0$ so there is $0<x_2<1$ that $f(x_2)=0$.

$f(1)<0$ and $f(2)>0$ so there is $1<x_3<2$ that $f(x_3)=0$.

$-2<x_1<0<x_1<1<x_3<2$

so

$x_1<x_2<x_3$, therefore they are different.

Also, $f'(x)=5x^4-4$, has only two roots, so there cannot be more than 3 roots for $f$ because there is a root of $f'$ between each two consecutive roots of $f$.

Comment: Yes, but I suppose my question is how to show that these are the only 3 roots that exist?

Comment: I am going to add it now!

Comment: @Oliver I added it.